# Parsing XML causes Error

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, parsing

Sorry for my bad English. I'm from Germany and have some problems with parsing my xml file. I use the latest version of the iOS SDK, including Xcode.

Parsing my xml file causes a well known error, called "Requesting for member 'Slices' in something not a structure or union"

Seems that I have forgotten something, initializing my Delgegate Class ?
Would be great if someone could help me through.
It's the only error I Get... narrf..

Here is some of the code, relevant for this problem:

My XMLParser .h File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class XMLAppDelegate, Slice;

@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{

    NSMutableString *currentElementValue;

    XMLAppDelegate *appDelegate;
    Slice *aSlice; 
}

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser;

@end
```

And here some parts of the .m File which shows the error:

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "XMLAppDelegate.h"
#import "Slice.h"

@implementation XMLParser

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser { 
    [super init];
    appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Channel"]) {
        //Initialize the array.
        appDelegate.slices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Slice"]) {

        //Initialize the slice.
        aSlice = [[Slice alloc] init];

        //Extract the attribute here.
        aSlice.sliceID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

        NSLog(@"Reading id value :%i", aSlice.sliceID);
    }

    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}
```

The error shows up after I try to use the slices array of my delegate.

Would be great if someone knows what to do,
this little thing makes me sick. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing the XML file didn't do anything, because you haven't gotten that far. Your program will only parse XML when it runs; your code has not run yet, because it does not compile.

The error is in compilation (which is why you're seeing it in Build Results), and is a syntax error: You have tried to use a name that the compiler does not recognize as valid for the place where you used it.

Specifically:

> ```
>         appDelegate.slices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
> ```

The compiler doesn't know that `appDelegate` has a `slices` property; as such, it falls back on its C roots and complains that you're trying to do a structure access to something that isn't a structure. You show in your code that you imported the header for the AppDelegate class, so the problem must be that you didn't declare the `slices` property in that class's `@interface`.

Comment: I checked my Delegate class an it looks like i've declared the slices property: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XMLAppDelegate : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
 
 NSMutableArray *slices;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *slices;

@end

Comment: That looks right, inability to format code in comments aside, but the problem remains: The compiler does not know that the object you're trying to use a property of has the property you're trying to use. Either the error is on a line of code you didn't show (I notice that the error message in your question says “Slices” rather than “slices”), or you didn't actually import the header in your real code, or you didn't actually declare the property in the header in your real code. I'm currently leaning toward #1. Note that you can double-click on build errors to go to the problem code.

Comment: The error is shown right in the line: appDelegate.slices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; , in the XMLParser.m   My fault,sorry.. i mean "slices", not "Slices". Just wrote it wrong above. I can't figure out why it can't use the slices property.

Comment: Me either. Everything you've shown looks right. Try compiling with Clang; it has better diagnostics than GCC.

Comment: "@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *slices;" I doubt you want this to be an IBOutlet. I'd be surprised if this causes the problem you're having but it sticks out as strange.

Comment: The Outlet is just one of many ways i used to figure out why it can't use my slices property in the XMLParser.m  It's not the reason for the error. =/

Comment: The only reason to make something an outlet is to hook it up in IB. Since you can't do that with an array (since a nib cannot contain an array), there is no reason why this should be an outlet. But yeah, that shouldn't be the cause of the problem.

Comment: okay... i make it run.. but now i get another error in the log..  unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Zarakas: You should post that as another question (or search the existing questions; there is no shortage of people who have had that problem).